# How make a select dropdown to select an option value based on current time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select dropdown  with times in 30 min intervals like

```
11:00 AM, 11:30 AM, 12:00 PM, 12:30 PM, 1:00 PM
```

beginning from 0:00 AM and ending with 11:30 PM

```
<select id='time'>
  <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
  <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
  <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
  <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
 <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
 <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
 <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
 <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
 <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
 <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
 <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#time').val(.now()); // this wouldnt work it gives the current time which may be between 30 min 

});
```

I want this select dropdown to default to rounded to nearest higher time based on current time.

For eg. if the current time is 10:46 AM then the selected value should 11:00 AM and if the current time is 10:31 AM should also default to 11:00 AM.

Any pointers on achieving this using jquery or with normal javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Math.round` function to get the value to the nearest half hour:

```
Math.round(Date.now()/(30*60*1000))*(30*60*1000));
```

Construct a date object from this and get the time.

```
var date = new Date(Math.round(Date.now() / (30 * 60 * 1000)) * (30 * 60 * 1000));
$('#time').val(date.getHours()%12 + ":" + ("0"+date.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + " " + (date.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM"));
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/GsR6v/9/

Comment: thanks @Asad, i tried on jsfiddle, my time is 2:09 PM but it still defaulted to 11:30 AM. i made sure i added the time on the selectbox to include 2:30 PM

Comment: @Prady You need to add `2:00 PM`, not `2:30 PM`

Comment: i did ... i updated the question with the values on my select

Comment: wonderful... the only issue is its rounding of the lower time. for eg current time is 2:24pm but it shows 2:00PM it should show 2:30PM

Comment: @Prady That was because I had hardcoded the value to `2:00 PM` for testing purposes (the time is different where I am). Try the updated fiddle.

Comment: The issue i think is its adding a 0 to the minutes, the value i get for the time is 2:030 PM

Comment: @Prady Yeah, that was a mistake on my part. I should have used `slice`, not `substring`. Fixed.

Comment: That worked wonderfully .. thanks. i am accepting your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try to round the value of the Date something like this:

```
var date = new Date(Math.round(Date.now()/(30*60*1000))*(30*60*1000));
```

Then use this to set up the date:

```
$("select option").filter(function() {
  //may want to use $.trim in here
  return $(this).text() == <YourDate>; 
}).attr('selected', true);​
```

Try this on my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mC869/

Comment: I am not getting it. the value as per the code in fiddle returns 14:30 PM and my select has 2:30 PM